# Get decorators names in runtime before calling them in

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code

```
def func_protected(func):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper


def cls_decorator(cls):

    for name, func in list(cls.__dict__.items()):
        print(name, func)

    return cls


@cls_decorator
class SomeClass:

    @staticmethod
    @func_protected
    @do():
        return

    @classmethod
    @func_protected
    @run():
        return

    @staticmethod
    @perform():
        return

sc = SomeClass()
```

I need on the code line with `print(name, func)` find a list of class functions (also covered by classmethod, staticmethod) that contain decorator `func_protected`. So in the runtime, before execution of the functions, I need to find a way to get the following function names — `do` and `run`, skipping function `perform`.

Comment: imho no obvious way to do this since decorator modifies the function permanently. But you can add some custom code to keep track of the stack of decorators used in the decorator definitions.

Comment: I have used `inspect`, but got failed. Could you give me the right way?